# Input not an x.509 format

Tags: certificate, weblogic, keystore, keytool, jks

I'm trying to get some certificates sorted in an environment, however, I'm not able to import some .cer files into the keystore

I ran the following commands:

```
keytool -genkey -alias wlint -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore wlint.jks

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore wlint.jks -destkeystore wlint.jks -deststoretype pkcs12

keytool -v -certreq -alias wlint -keystore wlint.jks -file wlint.csr -ext ExtendedkeyUsage=serverAuth
```

I then sent off the .csr and received back root, end and intermediate certificates in X.509 format, they are just: root.cer, end.cer, intermediate.cer

I pasted the certs (including the BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE parts) into a .txt file, removed any spaces/empty lines, and am trying to import into my keystore via:

```
keytool -importcert -alias root -file root.cer -keystore wldev.jks
```

However, I am getting the following error: Input is not an X.509 format

But, if I run

```
keytool -printcert -file root.cer
```

It prints out just fine, so the format seems to be ok?

From my googling, it looks like the alias when trying to import the root.cer is the problem, apparently I need to use a matching alias, so wlint, but even when I use that, I get a public/private key mismatch error? And regardless, the wlint alias is reserved, I want to import the root.cer with the alias of root..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the end.cer, intermediate.cer and root.cer contents into a single file `cert-chain.cer`, which should look something like this...

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIG0TCCBLmgAwIBAgITHwAGfgp3Q2M46c3rQgADAAZ+CjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF
ADBNMRUwEwYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYFbG9jYWwxGDAWBgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFghzZXJ2
aWNlczEaMBgGA1UEAxMRU2VydmljZXNFbnRTdWJDQTEwHhcNMjExMjE0MDM1NjE2
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGLDCCBBSgAwIBAgITJgAAAFbNK4iCK/s9zQAGAAAAVjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF
ADARMQ8wDQYDVQQDEwZST09UQ0EwHhcNMjEwNTI4MDQzOTUwWhcNMjYwNTI4MDQ0
OTUwWjBNMRUwEwYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYFbG9jYWwxGDAWBgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFghz
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFJDCCAwygAwIBAgIQYPfYlvivlKZE1sdh3ALNDzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAR
MQ8wDQYDVQQDEwZST09UQ0EwHhcNMTExMDA0MDE0MTMyWhcNMjgwNDI1MjIyNTU3
WjARMQ8wDQYDVQQDEwZST09UQ0EwggIiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4ICDwAwggIK
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Validate the `cert-chain.cer` file can be understood by keytool.  This should print out the details of the 3 certificates..

```
keytool -printcert -file cert-chain.cer
```

Then import the certificate chain into your keystore, using the original alias...

```
keytool -import -keystore wldev.jks -alias wlint -file cert-chain.cer
```